# Build R from source with Windows 10

Tags: r, compiler-errors

I am trying to build R-3.2.2 from Source, and the following error keeps popping out:

```
gzio.h:38:18: fatal error:zlib.h: No such file or directory.
compilation terminanted
make[4]: *** [connections.d] Error 1
make[3]: *** [rlibs] error 2
make[2]: *** [../../bin/i386/R.dll] Error 2
make[1]: *** [rbuild] Error 2
make: *** [all] error 2
```

My machine is now with Windows 10.
The thing is that I have done this before, on Windows 8, but R version I did it was 3.1.2 - but it worked perfectly!

has any of you have a similar problem before?
Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Did you install [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/)?

Comment: Yes. I've tried on the other computer which I have this task before, and I got the same errors

Comment: To be sure, your version of Rtools is 33?

Comment: yes! Exactly this one

Comment: The errors are appearing after I type "make all recommended vignettes".

It start compiling, but then, after some other steps, gives me those errors.